# How to create PHP Ajax filter in a shopping store

Tags: php, ajax, shopping-cart

I have got a requirement where I need to add filters in a shopping cart store built on core PHP. Basically the product filtering will work similar to that of [this shopping store](http://www.watchshop.com/) . I am very new to AJAX, so I need your help from where should I start. Are there any good Jquery plugins which have similar features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have built applications in AJAX but those were relatively small. So I can't say I am a noob in it, but still I consider myself as new to it. Anyways thanks for your reply.

Comment: And what does this make different from anything you have done before with AJAX? What have you tried / set up yourself already?

Comment: Currently I have got all the filters working with PHP using GET methods. But it does not look clean on the front end. What I was thinking is passing PHP responses through json and get it work. But is it the best way to go.